# Escrow account releases funds imediately when configuring lock-in period

Tags: transactions, accounts, operations

Hoping for a simple scenario following [This](https://lightyeario.github.io/escrow-demo/#escrow) thread:

1) Creating wallets from master accounts

2) Funding the escrow wallet

3) Giving the lock - in time bound period

4) Releasing the amount locked in escrow to destination

First 2 steps are fine, but as soon as I define lock -in time bounds in step 3, the Transaction is done immediately, transferring the funds to destination.

Ideally, I was hoping that the amount should be locked in Escrow account, and on further transaction, it should then release it to destination.

This is what I did to configure 3 accounts namely source, escrow and destination :

```
  const account = new StellarSdk.Account(escrow.publicKey(), sequence)
       const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account,{
        fee: StellarSdk.BASE_FEE
      })
       .addOperation(Stellar.Operation.setOptions({
        masterWeight: 2, 
        lowThreshold: 2,
        medThreshold: 2, 
        highThreshold: 2,
        signer: {
          ed25519PublicKey: dest.publicKey(),
          weight: 1
      }

       }))
       .addOperation(Stellar.Operation.setOptions({
        medThreshold: 3,
        signer: {
          ed25519PublicKey: source.publicKey(),
          weight: 1
      }
       }))

       .setTimeout(10000)
       .build()

       transaction.sign(StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(escrow.secret()))
       return server.submitTransaction(transaction)
```

And then this transaction to serve lock in period and amount should be locked :

```
const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account,{ 
      timebounds: { minTime: time -20 ,
                   maxTime: time + 200 },
      fee:StellarSdk.BASE_FEE }) 
      .addOperation(
       Stellar.Operation.payment({
        destination: dest.publicKey(),
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        amount:  amt

       })
       )
       .addOperation(Stellar.Operation.setOptions({
        signer: { ed25519PublicKey: dest.publicKey(), weight: 0 }

       })
       )
       .addOperation(Stellar.Operation.setOptions({
        masterWeight: 1, // revert to original state
        lowThreshold: 0,
        medThreshold: 0,
        highThreshold: 0,
        signer: { ed25519PublicKey: source.publicKey(), weight: 0 }

       }))
       .build()

       transaction.sign(StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(escrow.secret()),  
       StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(dest.secret()))
       return server.submitTransaction(transaction)
```

But as soon as this Tx is submitted, the funds are immediately transferred to destination account. What I am missing ?

Comment: Have not drilled into your code yet, but why `timebounds: { minTime: time -20 , maxTime: time + 200 }`? The time range suggests your transaction is valid already when you make the function call, and so the funds are readily, immediately transferred. Do you mean some fixed `time` instead of a variable one?

Comment: @cesarm Thanks for your response. Basically  I configured the time range so that starting from now  to  200 sec in future the transaction should remain invalid. But from your comment it looks like it's just the opposite ?

Comment: for time=1553652000 (2am of today), your expression yields a range of 1553652000-20 to  1553652000+200. That means your transaction is only valid from 1:59:40am to 2:03:20am. So...seems you may want some range like { minTime: time +200 , maxTime: time + 2000 }

Comment: yeah, it's opposite. timebounds define the range where a transaction is *valid*.

Comment: @cesarm Please post your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, when time=1553652000 (2am of 2019-03-27), your expression yields a range of 1553652000-20 to 1553652000+200.

That means your transaction is **only valid** from 1:59:40am to 2:03:20am.

So...seems you may want some range like { minTime: time +200 , maxTime: time + 2000 } for your transaction to work in the future, instead of the immediate current moment.